# Java double checked locking

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, singleton, double-checked-locking

I happened upon an article recently discussing the double checked locking pattern in Java and its pitfalls and now I'm wondering if a variant of that pattern that I've been using for years now is subject to any issues.

I've looked at many posts and articles on the subject and understand the potential issues with getting a reference to a partially constructed object, and as far as I can tell, I don't *think* my implementation is subject to these issues. Are there any issues with the following pattern?

And, if not, why don't people use it? I've never seen it recommended in any of the discussion I've seen around this issue.

```
public class Test {
    private static Test instance;
    private static boolean initialized = false;

    public static Test getInstance() {
        if (!initialized) {
            synchronized (Test.class) {
                if (!initialized) {
                    instance = new Test();
                    initialized = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use it. The reason it works is because the instance will be fully instantiated before the initialized = true line is hit and assigning a boolean value in Java is an atomic operation (on every chipset I've ever used).

Comment: @Jono It depends on the compiler and the VM, if it works or not. The compiler can produce a bytecode that is _caching_ the value of `!initialized` expression, and thus missing if another thread changes the value of the `initialized` property. If the same code is run parallelly, the instance initialization can be executed twice.
Also, the JIT compiler can optimize this expression from a non-optimized bytecode. Just think: the VM has to evaluate the same expression, immediately after the other. A `dup` operation prevents the re-evaluation, and is a valid code transformation according to JLS.

Answer (score 26):

[Double check locking is broken](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html). Since initialized is a primitive, it may not require it to be volatile to work, however nothing prevents initialized being seen as true to the non-syncronized code before instance is initialized.

EDIT: To clarify the above answer, the original question asked about using a boolean to control the double check locking. Without the solutions in the link above, it will not work. You could double check lock actually setting a boolean, but you still have issues about instruction reordering when it comes to creating the class instance. The suggested solution does not work because instance may not be initialized after you see the initialized boolean as true in the non-syncronized block.

The proper solution to double-check locking is to either use volatile (on the instance field) and forget about the initialized boolean, and be sure to be using JDK 1.5 or greater, or initialize it in a final field, as elaborated in the linked article and Tom's answer, or just don't use it.

Certainly the whole concept seems like a huge premature optimization unless you know you are going to get a ton of thread contention on getting this Singleton, or you have profiled the application and have seen this to be a hot spot.

Comment: Double-checked locking *was* broken.  Don't forget to read the section entitled "Under the new Java memory model" at the end of your linked document, which shows how and why it works in JDKs 1.5 and above (i.e. over five years now).

Comment: @dtsazza, yes it could be fixed with volatile now, but the OP didn't have that, it was trying to solve it with a boolean.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle also [proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166685/1059372) that it was broken.

Answer (score 17):

That would work if `initialized` was `volatile`. Just as with `synchronized` the interesting effects of `volatile` are not really so much to do with the reference as what we can say about other data. Setting up of the `instance` field and the `Test` object is forced to *happen-before* the write to `initialized`. When using the cached value through the short circuit, the `initialize` read *happens-before* reading of `instance` and objects reached through the reference. There is no significant difference in having a separate `initialized` flag (other than it causes even more complexity in the code).

(The rules for `final` fields in constructors for unsafe publication are a little different.)

However, you should rarely see the bug in this case. The chances of getting into trouble when using for the first time is minimal, and it is a non-repeated race.

The code is over-complicated. You could just write it as:

```
private static final Test instance = new Test();

public static Test getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: But beware of creating the world on application startup. Lazy initialisation has its uses.

Comment: @rsp This is still lazy : while you don't access the class, it won't initialize. But it true that, is some case, we want the laziness to be really at the last moment...

Comment: @Tom - there's a typo on your return value

Comment: McDowell: I elided my `Test()` method. :) KLE: If you have such requirements about initialisation, I think the system you are working on has severe robustness issues.

Comment: Considering how rarely lazy initialization is actually necessary, and how much more rarely still class-level laziness is not sufficient, I just can't fathom how anyone could justify the mental work going into all these discussions about double-checked locking and whatnot.

Comment: Michael: People love crazy optimisation! It does you good to think about. For some purposes (say implementing `java.util.concurrent`) then it is very useful. Almost always, simple code is best for keepers.

Answer (score 13):

Double checked locking is indeed broken, and the solution to the problem is actually simpler to implement code-wise than this idiom - just use a static initializer.

```
public class Test {
    private static final Test instance = createInstance();

    private static Test createInstance() {
        // construction logic goes here...
        return new Test();
    }

    public static Test getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

A static initializer is guaranteed to be executed the first time that the JVM loads the class, and before the class reference can be returned to any thread - making it inherently threadsafe.

Comment: Your example is incorrect because *'instance'* field is not marked as *'final'*, so, it's not guaranteed that there is no thread that can see *'null'* value there.

Comment: I don't think that is true based on http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html#44557 and http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html#44630 - the final modifier only seems to affect the order of which fields are initialized. However this field should be final anyway in his usage, so I've updated the code regardless.

Comment: Be careful, as this is not lazy initialized.

Te prove that it is  not lazy initialized; 
Just add a static method `public static String getMessage() {
        return "A message";
    }`  and call it. And you will see that the singleton filed is instantiated when calling that static method.

Answer (score 6):

This is the reason why double checked locking is broken.

Synchronize guarantees, that only one thread can enter a block of code. But it doesn't guarantee, that variables modifications done within synchronized section will be visible to other threads. Only the threads that enters the synchronized block is guaranteed to see the changes. This is the reason why double checked locking is broken - it is not synchronized on the reader's side. The reading thread may see, that the singleton is not null, but singleton data may not be fully initialized (visible).

Ordering is provided by `volatile`. `volatile` guarantees ordering, for instance write to volatile singleton static field guarantees that writes to the singleton object will be finished before the write to volatile static field. It doesn't prevent creating singleton of two objects, this is provided by synchronize.

Class final static fields doesn't need to be volatile. In Java, the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) takes care of this problem.

See my post, [an answer to *Singleton pattern and broken double checked locking in a real-world Java application*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482092/singleton-pattern-and-broken-double-checked-locking-in-real-world-java-applicatio/3516238#3516238), illustrating an example of a singleton with respect to double-checked locking that looks clever but is broken.

Comment: If the change isn't guaranteed to be seen in other threads, doesn't that mean that synchronizing the method itself would also break?  I thought that was supposed to be safe.

Comment: @BillK There is a happens-before chain from any write inside the synchronized block to any read in a block synchronized on the same object.

Answer (score 2):

**Double-checked Locking** is the anti-pattern.

**Lazy Initialization Holder Class** is the pattern you should be looking at.

Despite so many other answers, I figured I should answer because there still isn't one simple answer that says why DCL is broken in many contexts, why it is unnecessary and what you should do instead. So I'll use a quote from `Goetz: Java Concurrency In Practice` which for me provides the most succint explanation in its final chapter on the Java Memory Model.

It's about Safe Publication of variables:

> The real problem with DCL is the assumption that the worst thing that can happen when reading a shared object reference without synchronization is to erroneously see a stale value (in this case, null ); in that case the DCL idiom compensates for this risk by trying again with the lock held. But the worst case is actually considerably worse—it is possible to see a current value of the reference but stale values for the object's state, meaning that the object could be seen to be in an invalid or incorrect state.
>
> Subsequent changes in the JMM (Java 5.0 and later) have enabled DCL to work if resource is made volatile , and the performance impact of this is small since volatile reads are usually only slightly more expensive than nonvolatile reads.
>
> However, this is an idiom whose utility has largely passed—the forces that motivated it (slow uncontended synchronization, slow JVM startup) are no longer in play, making it less effective as an optimization. The lazy initialization holder idiom offers the same benefits and is easier to understand.
>
> **Listing 16.6. Lazy Initialization Holder Class Idiom.**
>
> ```
> public class ResourceFactory
>     private static class ResourceHolder {
>         public static Resource resource = new Resource();
>     }
>
>     public static Resource getResource() {
>         return ResourceHolder.resource;
>     }
> }
> ```

That's the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the atomic data types in [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

If "initialized" is true, then "instance" MUST be fully initialized, same as 1 plus 1 equals 2 :). Therefore, the code is correct. The instance is only instantiated once but the function may be called a million times so it does improve the performance without checking synchronization for a million minus one times.

Answer (score 0):

There are still some cases when a double check may be used.

1. First, if you really don't need a singleton, and double check is used just for NOT creating and initializing to many objects.
2. There is a `final` field set at the end of the constructor/initialized block (that causes all previously initialized fields to be seen by other threads).

Answer (score 0):

I've been investigating about the double checked locking idiom and from what I understood, your code could lead to the problem of reading a partially constructed instance UNLESS your Test class is immutable:

> The Java Memory Model offers a special guarantee of initialization safety for sharing immutable objects.
>
> They can be safely accessed even when synchronization is not used to publish the object reference.

(Quotations from the very advisable book Java Concurrency in Practice)

So in that case, the double checked locking idiom would work.

But, if that is not the case, observe that you are returning the variable instance without synchronization, so the instance variable may not be completely constructed (you would see the default values of the attributes instead of the values provided in the constructor).

The boolean variable doesn't add anything to avoid the problem, because it may be set to true before the Test class is initialized (the synchronized keyword doesn't avoid reordering completely, some sencences may change the order). There is no happens-before rule in the Java Memory Model to guarantee that.

And making the boolean volatile wouldn't add anything either, because 32 bits variables are created atomically in Java. The double checked locking idiom would work with them as well.

Since Java 5, you can fix that problem declaring the instance variable as volatile.

You can read more about the double checked idiom in [this very interesting article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html).

Finally, some recommendations I've read:

- Consider if you should use the singleton pattern. It is considered an anti-pattern by many people. Dependency Injection is preferred where possible. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138012/1280385).
- Consider carefully if the double checked locking optimization is really necessary before implementing it, because in most cases, that wouldn't be worth the effort. Also, consider constructing the Test class in the static field, because lazy loading is only useful when constructing a class takes a lot of resources and in most of the times, it is not the case.

If you still need to perform this optimization, check this [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom) which provides some alternatives for achieving a similar effect to what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

The DCL problem is broken, even though it seems to works on many VMs. There is a nice writeup about the problem here http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075306/java-concurrency/can-double-checked-locking-be-fixed-.html.

> multithreading and memory coherency are more complicated subjects than they might appear. [...] You can ignore all of this complexity if you just use the tool that Java provides for exactly this purpose -- synchronization. **If you synchronize every access to a variable that might have been written, or could be read by, another thread, you will have no memory coherency problems.**

The only way to solve this problem properly is to avoid lazy initialization (do it eagerly) or to single check inside a synchronized block. The use of the boolean `initialized` is equivalent to a null check on the reference itself. A second thread may see `initialized` being true but `instance` might still be null or partially initialized.

Answer (score 0):

First, for singletons you can use an Enum, as explained in this question [Implementing Singleton with an Enum (in Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-with-an-enum-in-java)

Second, since Java 1.5, you can use a volatile variable with double checked locking, as explained at the end of this article: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html