# java - do I have to declare my shared listener member variable as volatile?

Tags: java, volatile

I have a simple class which does some calculations in its own thread and reports the results to the listener.

```
class Calculator extends Thread {
    protected Listener listener;

    public void setListener(Listener l) {
        listener = l;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            ... do something ...

            Listener l = listener;

            if (l != null) {
                l.onEvent(...);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At any time, the user can call *setListener(null)* if he doesn't want any events for a certain time period. So, in the *run()* function, I create a copy of the listener, so I can't run into a *NullPointerException* which might happen if the listener is set to null after the *!= null* condition check succeeded. In my case, I believe this is a correct alternative for synchronizing it.

My question is: should I declare here the listener member variable as volatile? I have been reading a lot about volatile, but all examples seem to target the basic data types (boolean, int, ...), and not Objects. So therefore, I am not sure whether Objects should/could be declared volatile as well. I believe I have to declare it as volatile, so the thread always has the latest version of the member variable, but I am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a suggestion -- not really answering your question I admit -- but would it work better to put an 'enabled' type flag on your Listener, and then rather than having the client set the Listener null or not-null, have it setEnabled(true) or setEnabled(false)?  That gets you around the problem of handling an inadvertent NPE, and also prevents you from having to periodically instantiate new Listener objects.

Comment: @Japer D., That's a really, really, really ugly solution you've got there.

Comment: @JimKiley I agree with you. However, I was simplifying my question, hence it looks a bit strange. Apologies for that.

Comment: @Крысa Why? Can you explain please?

Comment: @JaperD., Instead of allowing another object to set a member variable of another class to `null`, you should provide a state that can be queried (i.e. `isEventAvailable()`). If that evaluates to true, execute `onEvent`, otherwise do nothing. Also, if you ever want that thread to stop, you'll have to declare `running` to be `volatile`.

Comment: @Крысa I don't agree. There is nothing wrong with having no listener at a certain time, imho. It is also the default and initial scenario.

Comment: @JaperD., Well, kudos to whoever has to maintain that code!

Comment: @Крысa How would your code look like given that the listener can be null? I am interested to see what would be different. No offense by the way, just asking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. To guarantee that the `Calculator` thread sees a new value, set by another thread, you would have to make the variable volatile.

However, `volatile` is a quite low-level mechanism and seldom used in client code. I suggest you consider using `java.util.concurrent.AtomicReference` in this scenario, which makes sure these things works as expected.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the confirmation. I'll look into AtomicReference, I have to admit i ignored the new concurrent package for way too long.

Comment: Hehe.. me too, but that's because I try to avoid concurrency altogether as long as possible :-)

Comment: Even with an atomic reference, things can execute in such an order that a listener would receive an event call after it had been deregistered. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I don't see any advantage to using an AtomicReference (over volatile) in this application.  What am I missing?  What does it make "work as expected" in this application that doesn't "work as expected" anyway?

Comment: @EdStaub - I agree. I don't see any benefit of AtomicReference over volatile here.

Answer (score 3):

If you use this approach, you can no longer guarantee that a listener will not receive an event notification after `setListener(null)` returns. Execution could proceed as follows:

```
Listener l = listener; // listener != null at this point

// setListener(null) executes here

if (l != null) {
    l.onEvent(...);
}
```

If you need to be guaranteed that no events will be posted to a listener after it has been unregistered, then you need to use synchronized blocks. Declaring `listener` to be `volatile` won't help. The code should instead be:

```
public synchronized void setListener(Listener l) {
    listener = l;
}

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        ... do something ...

        synchronized (this) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onEvent(...);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the expense of `synchronized` all the time, you can do this:

```
if (listener != null) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onEvent(...);
        }
    }
}
```

This runs the slight risk that you will miss an event after setting a non-null listener. Declaring `listener` to be `volatile` would probably fix that.

Comment: That's exactly the reason why I copy the member variable. If setListener(null) is called, the local variable l in run() isn't changed. This way, I avoid the synchronization block. No?

Comment: @TedHopp, no, since he copies the content to a local variable.

Comment: @JaperD. - I realized that and completely revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Now I understand your concern. However, in my case, it isn't a problem that the listener still receives events (for some time) after it unregistered itself. However, in the general case this might be a problem. It's good that you added this for clarity.

Comment: FWIW, regarding your last code snippet, I remember that double-checked locking isn't working as expected in Java. I might be wrong here. I'll have to google it up. See for example http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625118/java-double-checked-locking.

Comment: @JaperD. - The double-check locking problem has to do with constructing a singleton. Here, where the issue is just setting or unsetting a reference to a presumably completely constructed listener, those problems don't arise.

Comment: The listener may be deconstructed after unsetting.  Double-checking is fixed as of JDK5 - _if_ listener is volatile.

Comment: +1 `volatile` usually introduces a false sense of security without fixing the fixing the problem. However, `volatile` has some use here in that the listener wont be unsafely published (although it probably wont be thread safe anyway...).