# update memory before synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile, double-checked-locking

it is mentioned in the Java Memory Model that: When a thread exits a synchronized block as part of releasing the associated monitor, the JMM requires that the local processor cache be flushed to main memory. Similarly, **as part of acquiring the monitor when entering a synchronized block, local caches are invalidated so that subsequent reads will go directly to main memory and not the local cache.**

so why in that code I must declare instance as volatile since when the second thread enters the synch block will go directly to main memory ??

```
public final class MySingleton {
  private static MySingleton instance = null;
  private MySingleton() { } 
  public static MySingleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
        if (instance == null) {
          instance = new MySingleton();
        }
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

I mean when another thread enters synch block and make the second check it is supposed to update from main memory as mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicated [Java Double Checked Locking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1625118/651140)

Comment: How do you arrive at this code without having read [The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)? Everything is explained there in easily understandable terms.

Comment: more explanations please ... I see that since threads when entering synch block local caches are invalidated so that subsequent reads will go directly to main memory , so thread B is supposed to update its instance value from main memory without need to be volatile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The race condition is this:

1. Thread A sees `instance == NULL` and is running this code `instance = new MySingleton();`. The write to `instance` is visible but the writes into `MySingleton` are not yet.
2. Thread B sees `instance != NULL` and starts working on instance.
3. Thread B is now working on an object whose construction it cannot see.

Making `instance` volatile solves the problem as the JDK memory specification, as of JDK5, guarantees that writes to non-volatile objects will not be seen out of order with respect to a write to a volatile object. So any thread that sees `instance != NULL` must see the instance itself.

Comment: Specifically, the writes done by MySingleton's constructor are not guaranteed to be seen by thread B.

Comment: but how thread B can see instance != null while thread A did not release the lock of synch (which means thread A did not flush its cache to main memory) .. so thread B should see the old value of instance = null.

Comment: The write is not locked in the cache. The cache is always flushing or it would get full and writes from the CPU would stall. Flushing the cache means *ensuring* it has flushed. Not flushing it doesn't glue anything in it.

Comment: By the way, the cache involved here on actual hardware is *not* a memory cache. It's the CPU's write posting buffer, read prefetch, and instruction reordering. Real caches are 100% SMP coherent. Java descriptions will typically be about a hypothetical machine that has no cache coherency but no write posting buffers. The real machines Java runs on are not like the imaginary, theoretical machines Java is defined in terms of. So some things not defined by Java as working will always work. And some failure modes in the hypothetical Java machine will fail on real hardware, but differently.

Comment: so thats why we need volatile to ensure the same ordering of instructions ... nice .. really great answer bro .. thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare it volatile otherwise there is no guarantee that two calls to getInstance() will return the same instance.

There is no guarantee that main memory will be accessed, only a cache-consistent value. i.e. all threads will see the same value.

BTW: You know of course its far more complex than needed. All you need is

```
public enum MySingleton {
     INSTANCE;
}
```

does much the same thing.