# Java double-checked locking solution?

Tags: java, synchronization, singleton, double-checked-locking

This is a followup from [Java double checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625118/java-double-checked-locking).

The following code snippet has 2 interesting characteristics.

1) It requires a call to a separate init() method before the object is ready for use. So volatile doesn't help (I know, why don't I just put the code in init() into the constructor? It's here for the purposes of illustration).

2) It uses a tmp variable to do the initialization and assigns to instance after initialization is complete.

```
if (instance == null) {
synchronized (mutex) {
    if (instance == null) {
        AClass tmpInstance = new AClass();
        tmpInstance.init();
        instance = tmpInstance;
    }
}
}
```

So, is this subject to the reordering problem, i.e., could instance be assigned to tmpInstance prior to tmpInstance.init() being called?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 2):

All that matters is that you are assigning to `instance` as the last operation, after all initialization is done. Since `instance` is (hopefully) volatile, this will ensure all initialization is visible to later readers.

BTW there is really no need for you to learn all the rules of allowed reorderings: that's compulsory reading only for JIT compiler implementors.

All you, as a Java programmer, need to keep in mind are the two simple guarantees that the Java Memory Model offers you (one is about `synchronized`, the other about `volatile`). The whole point of the JMM rewrite (as of JLS 3) was to allow us to program against a very simple concurrency model.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is this subject to the reordering problem, i.e., could instance be
>   assigned to tmpInstance prior to tmpInstance.init() being called?

No but it is subject to the visibility problem which volatile does solve.  So you should still declare `instance` volatile.

Now the reason why it is not subject to a reordering.  Normal stores cannot be reordered after a monitor enter.

http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

> 1st Operation:  MonitorEnter
>
> 2nd Operation:  NormalStore
>
> Can Reorder:  No