# Can the following Singleton be unsafe in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, singleton

I want to be sure that my Singleton instance is available safely and with minimum synchronization but I have doubt about the first if clause outside the synchronized block. Is it possible for the `INSTANCE` to have a not-null value when it isn't completely constructed? If so how can I solve the issue.

I think that including the whole `get()` block will reduce the efficiency because there will be so many configuration variables that must be read thousands of times per second from different part of program via this `get()` method.

```
public class ConfsDBLoader {

    private static ConfsDBLoader INSTANCE = null;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    private ConfsDBLoader() { //Codes loading the db objects
    }

    public static ConfsDBLoader get(){
        if(INSTANCE != null){
            return INSTANCE;
        } else {
            synchronized(lock){
                if(INSTANCE == null){
                    INSTANCE = new ConfsDBLoader();
                }
                return INSTANCE;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

NOTE: I cant use static initialization because my hibernate sessionFactory is initialized statically and I want to have complex static structures that need each other. In fact I already have it and I'm not interested to make it more and more complex and investigate where these these static attributes try to use each other.

Comment: I assume you know there are simpler alternatives which have been around for about ten years. Can you let us know what you considered and why they were not appropriate?

Comment: You are using a very old and very well-known anti-pattern. It's not thread safe. A second caller can find a non-null INSTANCE while the first caller is still initialising it.

Comment: You mean that I should nest two synchronized? But it is not efficient!

Comment: I am suggesting you use a SingletonHolder or an `enum`, neither use synchronization at all.  Can you say why you don't use those?

Comment: @gnasher729 You are right, the field has to be `volatile`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java double checked locking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625118/java-double-checked-locking)

Comment: But SingletonHolder and enum are both eager! I'm trying to let this part of code be run on the first call in the non static body of the program.

Comment: @Johnny: None of them is eager. You are trying to “optimize” a problem that simply doesn’t exist.

Comment: @Johnny Classes are lazily loaded. What do you mean by eager?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

No. There is not enough synchronization to make sure that you are seeing the correct value on INSTANCE. You may see a non-null, but corrupt instance if your ConfsDBLoader because it may not be properly constructed by the time another thread calls getInstance().

You have 3 choices:

- Eager initialize and make final
- Synchronize whole method
- Make INSTANCE `volatile`

Comment: I reject the first two ones but will it work only with volatile keyword?! That's what I doubt. And will it be enough efficient?

Comment: @Johnny Define what you mean by "efficient enough"?

Comment: @Johnny synchronizing the whole method has some overhead, but how often are you going to call the get method? At some point, you will cache a local instance in your class, right? If I had to choose between the two, and loading the object eagerly is not an issue, I'd just choose option 1.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey ... are the sync between threads atomic when INSTANCE is being set? I've never really tried to find ways to break volatile, but that was my first thought since I've only really known it as a way to keep the value in sync in general, but not from context of atomicity. Would be good to know!

Comment: @coffeeaddict `volatile` has the memory barriers you need.