# Visibility of a read after synchronized block

Tags: java, java-memory-model

Does JMM guarantee the visibility of a `synchronized` write to the variable that is read in the other thread after a `synchronized` block? Here's what I mean:

```java
public class SynchronizedWriteRead {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public void writer() {
        synchronized (this) {
            a = 5;
            b = 7;
        }
    }

    public void reader() {
        synchronized (this) {
            int r1 = a; /* 5 */
        }
        int r2 = b; /* ? */
    }
}
```

JMM guarantees that an unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor. But I'm not sure if it relates only to the `synchronized` block body or not.

Recently I'm encountered this post from Aleksey Shipilëv - [Safe Publication and Safe Initialization in Java](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_arm). It says:

> Notice how doing `synchronized` in **Unsafe DCL** store does not help,
> contrary to layman belief it somehow magically "flushes the caches" or
> whatnot. Without a paired lock when reading the protected state, you
> are not guaranteed to see the writes preceding the lock-protected
> write.

So this is why I asked myself this question. I couldn't find an answer in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5).

Let's put it another way. Sometimes you're piggybacking on a `volatile` *happens-before* guarantee like this:

```java
public class VolatileHappensBefore {

    private int a; /* specifically non-volatile */
    private volatile int b;

    public void writer() {
        a = 5;
        b = 7;
    }

    public void reader() {
        int r1 = b; /* 7 */
        int r2 = a; /* 5 */
    }
}
```

You're guaranteed to see both writes because sequential actions in the same thread are backed by happens-before, and happens-before itself is transitive.

Can I use a `synchronized` *happens-before* guarantee the same way? Maybe even like this (I've put `sync` variable to forbid the compiler/JVM to remove otherwise empty `synchronized` block):

```java
    public void writer() {
        a = 5;
        b = 7;
        synchronized (this) {
            sync = 1;
        }
    }

    public void reader() {
        synchronized (this) {
            int r = sync;
        }
        int r1 = a; /* ? */
        int r2 = b; /* ? */
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use a `ReentrantLock` instead? one thread locks (or waits to lock), writes, unlocks, the other one locks (or waits to lock), reads, unlocks ? Sure, there is some ovearhead in the threads, in the form of waiting for the lock to free-up but whats the real issue? ... Other than ReaderThread obtaining the lock first and seeing no new values; if these are supposed to be a lock-step kind of thing then simply `synchronized` won't help there.

Comment: @Shark it's a barely practical question but more theoretical. I'm just trying to understand jmm better. So let's stick with these basic synchronization primitives

Comment: "I've put `sync` variable to forbid the compiler/JVM to remove otherwise empty `synchronized` block" I don't think an empty synchronized block can be optimized away, because of the change to the memory model semantics.

Comment: ok, then to answer your question - due to the `synchronized` writer block, `a` will most certainly be 5 due to the happens-before. however, since the code is procedural, `b` will either be 0 (due to it not being initialized to anything) or 7, and i'm gonna guess it's most likely going to be 7, because it's preceded by a `synchronized` block. If you however first read `b` then read `a` in a `synchronized` block, then `b` will be either 0 or 7, no guarantees, due to an implicit and obvious data-race.

Comment: However, since there is no code that illustrates or demonstrates how the `reader()` and `writer()` code is being called (with different threads or not), i can't really give you a unified answer that covers both examples, since in the first sample, `a` is specifically non-volatile, so it's prone to LTS (local thread caching) and it's going to be different for all threads unless made `volatile`. The second sample doesn't specify what `a` and `b` are, and we can only guess that they share the same declaration as in the first block.

Comment: Either way, i'd either suggest usage of a doubly-locked block (doubly checked locking is what you wanna read on, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625118/java-double-checked-locking#1625180)), or think about your usecase, and redesign it to not rely on just JVM but actual real `Lock`s. And you'll most likely want to use a `ReentrantLock` in that case, because it' can be a shared, reusable lock.

Comment: And i'm not even going to touch the fact that "double-checked locking is an antipattern" with a 10 foot stick here, because it's outside of the scope of your question or this "purely rhetorical/theoretical question".  I personally don't think it's an antipattern or consider it one, but if it really is - it's not a horrible one, the benefits outweight it's cost.

Comment: ... and then he kicks the "fact" hard.  Nah ... not biting :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's important to note here is that *happens-before* is a **transitive** relation. So if `A` happens-before `B` and `B` happens-before `C`, we can safely conclude that `A` happens-before `C`.

Now let's look at the code in question (I've added comments for clarity):

```
public void writer() {
    a = 5; //1
    b = 7; //2
    synchronized (this) { 
        sync = 1;
    } //3
}

public void reader() {
    synchronized (this) { //4
        int r = sync;
    }
    int r1 = a; //5 
    int r2 = b; //6
}
```

We know that `1` happens-before `2` and `2` before `3` since they're executed by the same thread:

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

We also know that `3` happens before `4`:

> An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

> If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).

Lastly, we know that `4` happens-before `5` and `5` before `6` since they're executed in the same thread.

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

So we end up with a chain of happens-before relationships from 1 to 6. Consequently, `1` happens-before `6`.

Comment: The happens-before edge between 3 and 4 only exists if 4 observes the 'sync' value written by 3. Since nothing is done with the read 'sync' value, we do not know if the value was observed and therefore no happens-before edge exists for all executions and hence there is data-race. To solve this problem you need to do something with the read 'sync' value that would prevent continuing if the 'sync' value was not set.

Comment: It becomes even more interesting if 0 would be written to sync instead of 1. Because then the synchronized blocks might have no semantics within the JMM at all.

Comment: @pveentjer isn't this called happens-before consistency? I mean you are correct that `(4)` has to observe `(3)` in order for the proper edge to be created, but the name for this rule would be "happens-before consistency"

Comment: There is no 'rule' happens-before consistency that is comparable to e.g. program order rule, or volatile variable rule, or monitor lock rule. Happens before consistency means that either a read the most recent write before it in the happens-before order, or a write it is in data-race with.

Comment: But yes; the code above has a data race and hence it needs to conform to the definition/rule of happens-before consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You got your answer by now, and to be fair, everyone here is correct, I just want to add one important rule. It's called "happens-before consistency", which goes like this:

- reads either see the latest write in happens-before order, or *any other* write not tied in happens-before order, thus a data-race.

So while the accepted answer is indeed correct, it should mention that in order for a happens-before edge to be created between `(3)` and `(4)`, `(4)` has to *observe* the write that `(3)` did.

In your example:

```
public void reader() {
   synchronized (this) {
      int r = sync;
   }
   int r1 = a; /* ? */
   int r2 = b; /* ? */

}
```

it means that `int r = sync;` is not correct, you need to assert that you actually saw `sync` to be `1` (you have observed the write). For example, this would create the needed edge:

```
if (sync == 1) {
    // guaranteed that r1=5 and r2=7
    int r1 = a;
    int r2 = b;
}
```

Comment: You still need to ensure that you read a/b only after you enter that side of the branch. Otherwise you still have a data race. So if you would do 'if(sync==0)return;' that would introduce the hb-edge. But the example is still very artificial.

Comment: Oh, yes. This is my mistake, thank you for fixing and clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

> Does JMM guarantee the visibility of a `synchronized` write to the variable that is read in the other thread after a `synchronized` block?

> Can I use a synchronized happens-before guarantee the same way?

Yes and yes.

`synchronized` and `volatile` give the same visibility guarantees.

In fact, a `volatile` variable behaves as if each read and write of this variable happens in its own tiny `synchronized` block.

In the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) terms:

- the visibility is guaranteed by the *happens-before* relation:

  > Informally, a read *r* is allowed to see the result of a write *w* if there is no happens-before ordering to prevent that read.
- `volatile` and `synchronized` are some of the ways to establish the *happens-before* relation:

  > - An unlock on a monitor *happens-before* every subsequent lock on that monitor.
  > - A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) *happens-before* every subsequent read of that field.
  > - ...

---

The quote from [Safe Publication and Safe Initialization in Java](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_arm) describes the case when:

- an object is initialized in a `synchronized` block in one thread
- the object and is read **without** `synchronized` blocks in another thread.

In this situation the reader thread might see the object in the middle of initialization.

Answer (score 1):

> Does JMM guarantee the visibility of a synchronized write to the variable that is read in the other thread after a synchronized block?

Yes, for the reasons given in the other answers.

But there is a catch.

Let us assume that the `reader` call follows the `writer` call so that there is a *happens before* between the `writer` exiting its synchronized block and reader entering its block ... and transitively it exiting the block and reading `b`.

The catch is when `reader` exits its block, there is no longer a guarantee of mutual exclusion on `b`.  So suppose that another thread immediately acquires the mutex and modifies `b`.  Since there is no HB chain connecting *that* write to `b` with the read in `reader`, there are no guarantees what the `reader` code will actually see *that* update ... or the value that `writer` wrote previously.

In short, you need to consider **more** than HB relationships when reasoning about concurrent algorithms.

Comment: Isn't it allowed to read without mutual exclusion if there's only single writing thread at any given time?

Comment: @TwITe: no. Because then you would not have a happens-before edge between the write and the read and weird things can happen like the compiler optimizing out the load. If you want to have a super cheap read that isn't optimized out and is atomic, you could have a look at the VarHande getOpaque. But keep in mind that technically it is still a data race and you really need to know what you are doing.

Comment: Also, it depends on what you mean by "allowed".  The compiler will allow you to write code that isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @pveentjer but keep in mind that `getOpaque` does not provide the transitivity (that’s why it is cheap). Especially important in a question about piggybacking…

Comment: @Holger correct. It doesn't provide happens-before edges and therefor transitivity doesn't apply.